# Does Enunicate maven plug-in could generate the data model which in other java project?

Tags: java, maven-plugin, enunciate

Would you please help me to fix a problem I met that to use Enunciate maven plug-in?  The problem is my domain is in other project, not in API project (not package, but java project), so when generate the documents, there is no data model, but I create a data model (@XmlRootElement) in the same project of API, it generated.  So, does the plug-in could generate the data model which in other project?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [FAQ](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/ENUNCIATE/FAQ). The first question links to [this document](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/ENUNCIATE/Multi-Module+Projects) which teaches you how to "import" classes into the project.

Answer (score 0):

1.**Export sources** from your external API project
You can add this to the API project or to the parent project in case this API project it's a module

```
<project ...>
...
 <build>
   ...
  <plugins>
    ...
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
       <execution>
         <id>attach-sources</id>
         <phase>package</phase>
         <goals>
           <goal>jar</goal>
         </goals>
       </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>
</project>
```

2.**add a reference to the package** in your enunciate.xml file

```
 <enunciate ...>
  <api-import pattern="com.mycompany.pck1.dao.*" />
 </enunciate ...>
```

3.**create the dependency to the sources** of the external project.

```
<project ...>
  ...
 <dependencies>
  ...
   <dependency>
     <groupId>...</groupId>
     <artifactId>domain</artifactId>
     <version>...</version>
     <classifier>sources</classifier>
     <scope>compile</scope>
     <optional>true</optional>
   </dependency>
   ...
  </dependencies>
```

** enunciate will try to compile your code so you need to add all the dependencies to external libraries

More Help: [Multi-module projects](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/ENUNCIATE/Multi-Module+Projects)